# How was the law of total probability used here for this conditional probability to get this result?

Tags: conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, uniform-distribution

If $X(t)$ is observed at a random time $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$, then, by the law of total probability, we have that
$$P(X(U) = k \mid X(0) = 1) = \int_0^\infty P(X(u) = k \mid X(0) = 1) g_U(u) \ du,$$

where

$$g_U(u) = \begin{cases} 1, & 0 < u < 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

How was the law of total probability used here for this conditional probability to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation is an application of the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) conditioning on events $U=u$, integrated over all values $u$ in the support of $U$.  Here is a more explicit version of the same working:

$$\begin{align}
p(X(U) = k|X(0) = 1) 
&= \int \limits_\mathbb{R} p(X(U) = k|X(0) = 1, U=u) \ g_U(u) \ du \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^1 p(X(u) = k|X(0) = 1) \ du \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$